# Python open() flags for open or create

Tags: file, python-3.x, mode

What is the mode for [open(..., mode)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) in Python 3 that opens a file that

- create if does not exist
- do NOT truncate
- binary mode

I tested `r+b` but that fails on missing file, `w+b` truncates it, and `a+b` seem to turn all writes into appends, while I need to overwrite some data.

Comment: Your answer introduces a race condition. See the other answer for an explanation. You should consider editing or changing the accepted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This is a massive deficiency in C & Python. There's no way to do this via `open()`!!

Python's `open()` is like the `fopen()` API in C, and neither has this ability.

Note that the `try`/`except` approach you posted has a **race condition**:
The file can be created in between the two calls, and suddenly you'll truncate it with the second call.

#### However: you can achieve what you want using **`os.open()`** and **`os.fdopen()`**:

```
fd = os.open(path, os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR | os.O_BINARY)
if fd != -1:
    f = os.fdopen(fd, 'r+b')  # Now use 'f' normally; it'll close `fd` itself
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to catch the exception and open with another mode. I would still accept a better solution.

```
try:
    self.file = open(filename, "r+b")
except FileNotFoundError:
    self.file = open(filename, "w+b")
```

Comment: Well what do you mean by overwriting some data ?